# mvc drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlistitem

```
IEnumerable<DeliveryRunRecord> deliveries = _deliveryRunService.GetAll();
List<SelectListItem> listOfDeliveryRuns = deliveries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name,
                Selected = "Select".ToString()
            }).ToList();
```

Would like 'Select' to appear before the drop down is selected, but not available when it is clicked, only allowing the user to select the values in deliveries??

Comment: you would have to do with javascript, have you tried that?

Comment: no i haven't, any ideas?

Comment: At the risk of sounding unhelpful you could search google, basically you would fire a function on selection of the select, that would remove this option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another item for default selection like this:

(This approach requires System.Linq namespace to be included)

```
SelectListItem defaultItem = new SelectListItem 
{ 
    Selected = true, 
    Text = "Select", 
    Value = "NONE" 
};
List<SelectListItem> listOfDeliveryRuns = deliveries
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name,
        Selected = false
    })
    .ToList()
    .Insert(0, defaultItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do what you are asking for in your .cshtml as well.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryId", new SelectList(ViewBag.deliveries as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Key", "Value"), "--Select--")
```

The above will display the dropdown list with "--Select--" as the item selected by default. I have just copied a sample which used a Dictionary with your item values and is passed in as a parameter through ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

[Selected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected(v=vs.118).aspx) of SelectListItem is Boolean type so you can not assign string it should be false or true.

But what you want achieve can be simply done on view.
 @Html.DropDownList("dropdown1", new SelectList(ViewBag.deliveries , "Value", "Text", **0**), "please select", new { onchange = "form.submit();" })

Pay attention to fourth parameter on DropDownList Method, it's **zero**.

I hope this helps.